Extracting/classifying quantitative information from character variable
I have a data.frame of the following type



id
text_information




1
Increase from 10.81% to 60.1%


2
Purchase 100.00 %


3
Increase from 5.9% to 45.48%


4
Purchase 99.0%



I would like to process the text_information (character) variable such that I obtain the following output:



id
share
share_difference
type




1
0.601
0.492
increase


2
1
NA
purchase


3
0.455
0.396
increase


4
0.99
NA
pruchase



A suggestion how this could be done using R?

Use regular expressions:
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data.frame(
  id = 1:4,
  text_information = c(
    "Increase from 10.81% to 60.1%", 
    "Purchase 100.00%", 
    "Increase from 5.9% to 45.48%", 
    "Purchase 99.0%"
  )
) %>% 
  mutate(
    share_1 = as.numeric(str_extract(text_information, "(\\d+\\.\\d+)%", 1)),
    share_2 = as.numeric(str_extract(text_information, "(\\d+\\.\\d+)% to (\\d+\\.\\d+)%$", 2)),
    share = if_else(is.na(share_2), share_1, share_2) / 100,
    share_difference = (share_2 - share_1) / 100,
    type = tolower(str_extract(text_information, "(Increase|Purchase)"))
  ) %>% 
  select(id, share, share_difference, type)
#>   id  share share_difference     type
#> 1  1 0.6010           0.4929 increase
#> 2  2 1.0000               NA purchase
#> 3  3 0.4548           0.3958 increase
#> 4  4 0.9900               NA purchase

Created on 2024-04-08 with reprex v2.1.0

This code perfectly does the job. I did just oversimplify the data. In fact, there are also decimals, which I now changed in the edited version of my question. Do you have a simple solution to the problem?

data.frame( id = 1:4,
text_information = c( "Increase from 10.81% to 60.1%",
"Purchase 100.00%",
"Increase from 5.9% to 45.48%",
"Purchase 99.0%"))

just change the regular expressions to pick up the decimals. see edit.

Using dplyr and tidyr
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Create dataframe
id <- c(1,2,3,4)
text_information <- c("increase from 10% to 60%", "Purchase 100%","Increase 
from 5% to 45%","Purchase 99%")
df <- data.frame(id,text_information)

# Processing text
df %>% 
  mutate(text_num = trimws(gsub("[^0-9 ]", "", text_information))) %>%
  separate(text_num, into=c("v1","v2","v3"), sep = " ", fill = "left") %>% 
  mutate(share=as.numeric(pmax(v1,v3,na.rm=TRUE))/100,
     share_difference = (as.numeric(v3)-as.numeric(v1))/100,
     type = if_else(is.na(share_difference),'purchase','increase')) %>% 
  select(text_information,share,share_difference,type)

